# Javascript Sqlite Database select query with multiple parameters where any of them can be null

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Its relatively trivial in Sqlite to do a select with multiple where clauses. However I am simply stumped to find a way to do multiple where clauses where any of the parameters can be null. Basically I have a multi drop-down screen where the query is generated on the fly based on the selections made on each of the dropdowns. It works fine when there are values in the parameters but it doesnt work when some of the dropdowns are left blank.

My select query is like this:

```
   tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tableOne WHERE id=?, name=?, address=?', [id, name, addredd], records);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: And what should happen when such a value is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to dynamically construct `where` clause based on selection

or

you can use `like` operator instead of `where`, passing `empty` strings instead of `NULL` values.